# obtener el id de un array php

Tags: php, array, cakephp

Tengo este array

```
object(stdClass)[138]
  public 'articles' => 
    array (size=39)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[140]
          public 'id' => int 56
          public 'title' => string 'prueba con servicio json es tt aa' (length=33)
          public 'body' => string 'prueba de hoy' (length=13)
          public 'created' => string '2018-06-22T19:49:34+00:00' (length=25)
          public 'modified' => string '2018-06-22T19:49:34+00:00' (length=25)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[139]
          public 'id' => int 55
          public 'title' => string 'prueba con servicio json es tt' (length=30)
          public 'body' => string 'prueba de hoy' (length=13)
          public 'created' => string '2018-06-22T19:49:12+00:00' (length=25)
          public 'modified' => string '2018-06-22T19:49:12+00:00' (length=25)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[137]
          public 'id' => int 54
          public 'title' => string 'prueba jhon bernal json' (length=23)
          public 'body' => string 'prueba de hoy' (length=13)
          public 'created' => string '2018-06-22T19:46:55+00:00' (length=25)
          public 'modified' => string '2018-06-27T19:05:45+00:00' (length=25)
```

quiero realizar una operacion para obtener solo un object de acuerdo a su id.

```
 object(stdClass)[137]
          public 'id' => int 54
          public 'title' => string 'prueba jhon bernal json' (length=23)
          public 'body' => string 'prueba de hoy' (length=13)
          public 'created' => string '2018-06-22T19:46:55+00:00' (length=25)
          public 'modified' => string '2018-06-27T19:05:45+00:00' (length=25
```

Comment: Precisamente... ¿qué quieres decir con *obtener solo un object de acuerdo a su id.*? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que quieres obtener?

Comment: que me muestre su id = 54, title = prueba jhon bernal json, que se vean asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongamos que el objeto que muestras se llama `$objArticles`, tendrías que:

- acceder al array de objetos que hay dentro de la propiedad `articles`
- recorrer ese array de objetos buscando la propiedad/valor que te interesa.
- una vez encontrada, puedes usar **[`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-object-vars.php)** para crear un array con todas las propiedades no estáticas de esa parte únicamente

El código quedaría así:

```
$arrArticles=$objArticles->articles;
$arrResult=array();

    foreach ($arrArticles as $theArticle) {

        if ($theArticle->id==54){
              $arrResult =get_object_vars($theArticle);  
        }
    }

print_r($arrResult);
```

*That's all!*  Usa `$arrResult` según tu necesidad.